# applescript will not run macro on a duplicate excel instance

Tags: excel, applescript

Here is the script I got so far:

```
set application_name to "Microsoft Excel_2"

tell application application_name to launch

tell application "System Events"

 repeat until visible of process "Microsoft Excel" is false
     set visible of process "Microsoft Excel" to false
 end repeat

end tell

tell application application_name

 open "/Users/ben/Desktop/Emod_Calc/Emod_Calc_2020.xlsm"
 run VB macro "SaveReportAsPDFIn2020"

end tell
```

I am able to open desired excel file in the second instance but it does not recognize the command to run the macro.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A variable can't be used for the target of a tell statement - the scripting terminology for any given application needs to be declared at _compile_ time.

Comment: @red_menace well its interesting because if I comment out the "run VB macro" part of the code it triggers performs perfectly

Comment: Try e.g.: `set application_name "/Applications/Microsoft Excel_2.app"` or if that doesn't work, then try e.g.:  `tell application  "/Applications/Microsoft Excel_2.app"` In either case use the _fully qualified POSIX pathname_ including the `.app`.

Comment: Some of the standard suite such as `open` and `launch` may work, but the application must be declared at compile time to load its scripting terminology.  The application reference needs to be an absolute object specifier instead of something ambiguous such as a property or variable.